# out-lineoutput : Length cannot be less than zero (PowerShell error)

Tags: powershell, printing, dymo

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uTLE.png) Hi there I am trying to print the contents of a PDF document to a label maker and am struggling to get it to work. When I print to a regular computer I get no problems but when I try the label printer it keeps giving me this error and I don't know what to do. I am trying to print the data to a DYMO LabelWriter 450 Duo Label, it may be just a dymo thing but I'm lost

I've tried printing to a regular printer and the works fine but that label writer keeps giving me these errors (https://i.stack.imgur.com/elv4i.png)